# Eth Beginner Problems

Tags: erc-721, brownie

For the last couple days I've been trying to create my first NFT project so I've been following the beginners guides. Long story short the 'brownie' command WILL NOT WORK so I cant even get started unfortunately... Brownie is installed but every time I type the command 'brownie' I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Wes>brownie
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main

    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\Scripts\brownie.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\brownie\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    from brownie._config import (

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\brownie\_config.py", line 15, in <module>
    from hypothesis import Phase

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hypothesis\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from hypothesis.core import example, find, given, reproduce_failure, seed

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hypothesis\core.py", line 71, in <module>
    from hypothesis.internal.conjecture.engine import ConjectureRunner

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hypothesis\internal\conjecture\engine.py", line 45, in <module>
    from hypothesis.internal.conjecture.pareto import NO_SCORE, ParetoFront, ParetoOptimiser

  File "C:\Users\Wes\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hypothesis\internal\conjecture\pareto.py", line 18, in <module>
    from sortedcontainers import SortedList
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sortedcontainers'
```

Comment: Hi WesleyBond! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! You can format verbatim code/error messages surrounding them with ``` before and after the text.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there's not so much provided data about your environment, but I can share the "basic install" for brownie that usually works 99% of the time for me on whatever OS available.

- Install python3 on your system (not anaconda)
- Install pip3: `py -3 -m ensurepip`
- Install virtualEnv to prevent you from messing your python install: `pip install virtualenv`
- When in your project's folder, create a virtual environment: `virtualenv venv`
- Start it : `source venv/bin/activate`
- Install brownie using pip, which will install all dependencies: `pip install eth-brownie`

Should be good then. I may recommend using wsl on Windows for more ease of use. If you have anaconda installed you may try to follow those steps with `pip` instead of `conda`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run brownie with anaconda. You're running into weird python issues.

I recommend uninstalling brownie

```
pip uninstall brownie
```

You'll know you did it right if `which brownie` returns nothing.

Then, install with `pipx`

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
```

Restart terminal

```
pipx install eth-brownie
```